# Can you create objects from a groupBy query?

Tags: linq, win-universal-app

Is there any way to direct the output of my groupBy query into an object?

```
var inspectionItemsGrouped = inspectionItems.GroupBy(item => item.SubCategory).Select(g => new
        {
            SubCategory = g.Key,
            Items = g.ToList(),
            ValidCount = g.Sum(c => !c.ReadOnly && c.IsValid ? 1 : 0)
        }).ToList();
```

I can create

```
class QueryResults {
   public string SubCategory {get;set;}
   public List<InspectionItem> Items {get;set}
   public int ValidCount {get;set;}
}
```

but I can't figure out how to attach it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new instance of the `QueryResults` class by putting it's name after the `new` statement, like that:

```
var inspectionItemsGrouped = inspectionItems
    .GroupBy(item => item.SubCategory)
    .Select(g => new QueryResults
        {
            SubCategory = g.Key,
            Items = g.ToList(),
            ValidCount = g.Sum(c => !c.ReadOnly && c.IsValid ? 1 : 0)
        }).ToList();
```

And as a suggestion, you probably could use a boolean on the `ValidCount` property, instead of using a int with zero or one.

Comment: ValidCount is a Sum, so I can't use a boolean, but this worked perfectly.  Thanks!